# create big image from small in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x

I searched on the net, examples of image gallery built as in the web pages following the principle of lightbox or fancybox, and to create in python. unfortunately, I did not find anything. As a result, I made this code that works well, but I have for each image to create a Toplevel that corresponds to it. which makes the code a little heavy.
here is the code in python 3.6 :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

def make_big_image1() :
    window_image=Toplevel(root)
    window_image.minsize(width=500, height=350)
    window_image.title("big image!")
    img=PhotoImage(file='images/big_images/big_image1.png')
    label = Label(window_image,image=img)
    label.image = img 
    label.pack()

def make_big_image2() :
    window_image=Toplevel(root)
    window_image.minsize(width=500, height=350)
    window_image.title("big image!")
    img=PhotoImage(file='images/big_images/big_image2.png')
    label = Label(window_image,image=img)
    label.image = img 
    label.pack()

def make_big_image3() :
    window_image=Toplevel(root)
    window_image.minsize(width=500, height=350)
    window_image.title("big image!")
    img=PhotoImage(file='images/big_images/big_image3.png')
    label = Label(window_image,image=img)
    label.image = img 
    label.pack()

small_img1=PhotoImage(file='images/small_images/small_image1.png')
small_img2=PhotoImage(file='images/small_images/small_image2.png')
small_img3=PhotoImage(file='images/small_images/small_image3.png')

bt1=Button(root, image=small_img1, command =make_big_image1)
bt1.pack()
bt2=Button(root, image=small_img2, command =make_big_image2)
bt2.pack()
bt3=Button(root, image=small_img3, command =make_big_image3)
bt3.pack()

lb=Label(root,text='click on image to make big image')
lb.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I need help to improve this code or to follow another alternative thank you

Comment: _"I need help to improve the code"_ is too broad and vague. What _specifically_ do you need help with?

Comment: instead of several functions depending on the number of images, I would like to build a single function to enlarge small images to big images